# Find all used CSS Selectors on a page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-devtools

At the beginning - I am sorry if title is not accurate. I just don't know how to call it properly.

Is there a way to find all paths related to some file, in my case it is `bootstrap.min.css` (it could be with unminified version) within a project? I mean, like on this screen:

[image]

So I want to find in DevTools (or may be in WebStorm, if it is simpler to do so) all Bootstrap paths that are related to all elements in project. At above screen i selected `<nav>` element with some Bootstrap classes, which I can see on the right. I emphased (red rectangle) Bootstrap CSS source file paths - already filtered by DevTools (orange rectangle). I could of course manually click on each link to exact line, but there are many HTML elements and some of them have multiple classes, there are few pages also. So it will take long time to click in all such links.

**Is there a quick way** to filter/find all such paths (that marked as red), which are used by Bootstrap CSS selectors to match all HTML elements in project?

Comment: I most likely found a tool, which solved my problem: https://uncss-online.com/ After placing there all my HTML, and on the other side, whole Bootstrap code - it output only those Bootstrap lines of code, which are really used in HTML classes.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open DevTools
2. Overflow Menu > More Tools > Coverage
3. Click record in the toolbar of the drawer panel
4. Stop recording and view results

When viewing results you will be taken to the appropriate file in the Sources panel. This will then highlight each line in the gutter either red or green to indicate whether or not it was used. This works for CSS and JavaScript.

[image: Access Coverage]
[image: Coverage View in Sources]